# Library to create chart in c#

Tags: c#, charts

I have a .Net Core 3.1 console application. The goal is to read data from an Excel document and save it in a database. Then various charts should be created from the data stored in the database. However, I do not find a free library for creating these charts. I don't want to use a GUI. Is there a simple library for C#?

Comment: As far I know, Office has many COM+ components, and those you could control in .net . Hopefully you will get an answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "don't want to use a GUI"; where is this chart supposed to display, do you want to create a file which contains a graph as I don't think you'll be able to display one in a basic console app.